# Unable to fit multiple simulators in the preview pane in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

When viewing UI simulators in the Xcode assistant preview pane - There is no way to view multiple simulators. I can only see the first simulator added, any additional simulators which I have added are placed offscreen and there is no scroll ability to move the preview view so as to see these other simulators.
Please help ...

Comment: To be able to help you, could you please tell us a bit more. I'm not sure you talk about **simulator** but **Preview - design**,  is that right? If preview, you can add other device size with `+` (back left). If simulator, you can run only one at a time.

Comment: I mean the UI previews ( eg. iPhone 4inch, 4,7inch etc.. ) - so yes I can add multiple previews by pressing the '+' key but I can only ever see the first UI preview as all additional UI previews Xcode places offscreen. It would be useful to add multiple UI previews and actually be able to see them on screen.

Comment: If by UI simulator you mean opening a 'xib' file in the assistant preview pane, and that xib contains at least a "View" object, then simply click in that view object. It will place it visible inside the pane. Depending on the situation, you might see your view(s) as simple icons or as a list, on the left-hand side of your pane. The "view" object appears below other important stuff such as "Application", "First Responder", "File Owner" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you successfully added previews but they are placed offscreen.

That is not really a problem, just zoom-out to see all previews. (Using pinch zoom on the trackpad)

Comment: Simple but True - Great Stuff Thanks MacKentoch.

Comment: Is there a way to pan and zoom if I have a mouse only as I work on a Mac Mini? I see that I can double click to zoom in/zoom out, but it only switches between two zoom states - between very small and 100%. Also I can't find a handy way to pan. Any ideas?